# How to individually change Code style color for files with .php extension in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I looked up the PHPStorm manual and also searched for related questions here, but I didn't find a solution. So I don't know if this is even possible.

(Note that one question here on StackOverflow has a similiar title as mine but what I mean is something different than asked there!)

I have a file with a .php-extension but I mainly edit JavaScript-code in there. But there are some lines where I need to work with PHP, that's why I include this PHP file. However because of this .php-extension there isn't any JavaScript recognized by the IDE. Is there a way to individually change a specific file formatting or handling it as JavaScript, even if it's a PHP file?

Comment: You can try to insert JS code after the PHP closing tag and re-open if you need to. Also, there is an option that allows you to change edit or create file types: Settings | Editor | File Types

Comment: That is already what I'm doing, open little php tags here and there, but the file is mainly JavaScript.

Comment: I saw that `File Types` option in Settings but I can't additionally assign JavaScript to `*.php`. Then it asks me if I want to reassign it, but I want to keep php style formatting for php files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File | Settings | Editor | File Types for Windows and Linux
PhpStorm | Preferences | Editor | File Types for OS X
Ctrl+Alt+S

Click this button to open the New File Type dialog and define a new custom file type there OR Click this button to open the Edit File Type dialog box and edit the selected file type there.

Comment: As I mentioned I'll overwrite my formatting to php files then: https://picload.org/image/rrrgpado/phpstorm.jpg But I don't want to lose this formatting to my php files.

Comment: Settings | Template Data Languages -- find your file(s) or folder(s) and assign JavaScript to them (instead of default HTML).

If you keep your stuff well organized, then you will benefit from keeping all *.js.php files under separate subfolder -- this allows single assignment for a whole folder (and all files inside) instead of multiple assignments for individual files.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I looked into it, but I can't change anything there. The "Apply" button is greyed out all the time, no matter where I click: https://picload.org/image/rrrgpodd/phpstorm2.jpg Any suggestions?

Comment: @Vaia It's easy -- just select desired Template Language in **2nd column**.

Comment: Ahh, great! I didn't know that's clickable. Thank you both! It works now.